# catch exception in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, exception, nullpointerexception

I want to know how to handle this situation and what do you recommend for this.

I am having a null pointer exception in my JSP.

```
String csvDataIn = new String ((String)request.getAttribute("csvString"));
```

This is because, I have created a Controller in spring in order to handle the querying to the DB and get a csvString. Everything is working fine, until I made a query that is failing.

So, in the controller:

```
    ...
   JsonNode json = dataRepository.getDataAsJson(dataNode);
   csvString = getCSVfromJsonNode(json);
              model.addAttribute("csvString", csvString);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.log("CSV controller failed", _moduleClass, e);
            }
            return "exportCSV";
      }
```

So the variable json is never been fill it, because the function getDataAsJson() is failing. So this is throwing an exception. And then I am returning back to the exportCSV.jsp, but I am not returning the attribute csvString in the model.

So, back in the jsp, is throwing the nullpointer exception.

So my questions are:
a- How you will catch this exceptions in the JSP?
b- Do you think a better solution, than catch the exception in the JSP? I mean what could be the best practice for this.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks for the responses. They are really good help: I made the following modifications in order to handle the problem.

```
    ...
         JsonNode json = dataRepository.getDataAsJson(dataNode);
         model.addAttribute("csvString", csvString);
       } catch (Exception e) {
         Logger.log("CSV controller failed", _moduleClass, e);
       }
       return "exportCSV";
       csvString = getCSVfromJsonNode(json);
       }
```

This solve the problem for sending a Null String, since the csvString is bean created before, empty.

The exception that I am getting in here is javax.xml.ws.webserviceexception could not send message (do you know a better way to handle this at the controller?)

I also did this in the jsp side, just in case:

```
String csvDataIn = (String)request.getAttribute("csvString");
//This should never happen, but we check anyway.
if (csvDataIn != null){
...
}
```

So the only doubt that I may remain is: do you know a better way to handle javax.xml.ws.webserviceexception at the controller?

THANKS AGAIN

Comment: The exception handling like what you're talking about belongs in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RuntimeException`s like `NullPointerException`s usually indicate programmer's errors in the code. I.e. it are bugs. You should not catch them, but avoid them by prechecking properly. In your particular case, you made the mistake to wrap it in another `new String()`. If the attribute is `null`, it will throw `NullPointerException` on that. Remove that.

E.g.

```
String csvDataIn = (String) request.getAttribute("csvString");

if (csvDataIn != null) {
    // Do your job here.
}
else {
    // Just ignore it?
}
```

But after all, business logic really doesn't belong in the JSP. You should do this job in the controller instead and give the JSP **exactly** the data it needs to decorate some HTML around. If you encounter a really unrecoverable exception in the controller, then rethrow it as a `ServletException`. It'll end up in the container's default error page, or the one which you specified as `<error-page>` in `web.xml`.

```
} catch (Exception e) { // Please be more specific.
    throw new ServletException("Converting to CSV failed", e);
}
```

Comment: The exception that I am getting in the controller is "javax.xml.ws.webserviceexception could not send message", do you know a better way to handle this? should you recomend to do an extra validation? (Like I told you before, I am asking this this is just because I want to learn how to handle exceptions in a better way.) THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWER

Comment: This is a serious exception, indicating that there's something wrong with your webservice request, or with the external webservice server itself. So far now you should let the exception go all the way up to the container so that it ends up in an error page. How to fix **the cause** of the particular exception is a story apart. I'd start reading the webservice API documentation or contacting the webservice support team how to solve the cause of the particular exception.

Comment: Thanks, I made a few more changes. I took the processing in the controller and added that in the repository. So now is going to fail at the repository. One more doubt and I will not bother you any more.. When you say "you should let the exception go all the way up to the container" you mean that the exception should go to the jsp and then handle the jsp failure with a failure page?

Comment: You should not catch and suppress it. You should let it go or rethrow it as another exception. I.e. add `throws SomeException` to the method, or wrap it in `new ServletException(e)`. It will ultimately be caught by the container and this way it will load and show the default error page.

Answer (score 1):

Better you initialize the `csvString` with an empty value instead of `null`. So it will always go to the jsp, if you have some valid value you will render that else you will display empty in the view.

Also please avoid using scriptlet code in the jsp. Its not maintainable.